# gem failed to install bropages

Tags: software-installation, ruby

There is an alternate manpage documentation software called bropages, written in ruby, and I want to install it. I followed the instructions on [the site](http://bropages.org/), but got these errors:

```
~$ sudo gem install bropages
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bropages:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/unf-0.2.0.beta2/ext/gems/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/unf-0.2.0.beta2/ext/gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.1/gem_make.out
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:38:in `block in build'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:677:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:232:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:78:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:206:in `block in install_into'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:198:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:198:in `install_into'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:119:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:389:in `install'
    from mkrf_conf.rb:15:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/unf-0.2.0.beta2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/unf-0.2.0.beta2/gem_make.out
```

Ruby gems aren’t something I’m familiar with, and I don’t see anything that clearly says error. So what has gone wrong here? How can I install bropages?

I tried `sudo apt-get install bro` but that is something else entirely.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably missing the ruby header files you need when compiling modules.

If you're on Debian/Ubuntu, install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Then try the bropages install again.

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing some required files to compile a native dependency required by this gem

Try running the following

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby2.1-dev
```

After this, try installing the bropages gem again and see if the error goes away or changes

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to install the dependencies.

From the [docs](https://www.bro.org/sphinx-git/install/install.html):

```
sudo apt-get install cmake make gcc g++ flex bison libpcap-dev libssl-dev python-dev swig zlib1g-dev
```